# Installation From Bootable USB Stick

Tags: system-installation

I have recently tried to install Elementary OS 0.4.1 from a bootable USB stick. But there comes a message on command line interface that something Live (I have forgotten the line) is not found. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a new USB live using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) on Windows machine using a freshly downloaded ISO from the [elementary](https://elementary.io/) website and try again.